# QDialog exec() (SEG FAULT)

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault

My QDialog is causing a seg fault after it closes. I malloc my struct before using it, settings is of type PSETTINGS and is a private variable.

**MainWindow Class:**(Seg Fault happens in `settingsDiag->exec()`)

```
Settings *settingsDiag = new Settings(this);

settingsDiag->exec();
```

**Settings Class:**

In header file:

```
typedef struct ConnSettings {
    ConnSettings():ipAddr(""), alias("Local"), port(8000), isClient(false){}
    QString ipAddr;
    QString alias;
    int port;
    bool isClient;
} SETTINGS, *PSETTINGS;
```

In CPP file:

```
Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QButtonGroup serviceGroup(ui->serviceBox);
    QValidator *validPort = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^\\d*$"), this);
    QValidator *validIp = new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}$"), this);

    serviceGroup.addButton(ui->clientButton);
    serviceGroup.addButton(ui->serverButton);

    connect(ui->okCancel, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(storeSettings()));
    connect(ui->clientButton, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(enableDisableClient(bool)));

    ui->portText->setValidator(validPort);
    ui->ipText->setValidator(validIp);
}

Settings::~Settings() {
    delete ui;
}

void Settings::storeSettings() {
    settings = (PSETTINGS)malloc(sizeof(SETTINGS));
    settings->port = ui->portText->text().toInt();

    if((settings->isClient = ui->clientButton->isChecked())) {
        settings->ipAddr = ui->ipText->text();
        settings->alias = ui->aliasText->text();
    }
}

PSETTINGS Settings::getSettings() {
    return settings;
}

void Settings::enableDisableClient(bool client) {
    ui->clientBox->setEnabled(client);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Ok. I'm new to this so I don't really know the standard yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The malloc is causing problems too.  The strings in that struct get used without being constructed.  Assume your heap corrupted after that point.

Instead of malloc try...

```
settings = new SETTINGS();
```

... and of course delete when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating the QButtonGroup serviceGroup on the stack. Probably not what you want to do.